# why echo after sed makes other lines end with ^M

Tags: shell, unix, sed, echo

```
#!/bin/ksh

FILE_NAME=pltlog.20130801152242
LINE_NOS=`grep -n "SEND MSEG" $FILE_NAME|awk -F: '{print $1}'`
sed -n "1,52p" $FILE_NAME
echo "This is a test"

#for start_line in $LINE_NOS
#do
#   ((end_line=start_line+51))
#   sed -n "$start_line, ${end_line}p" $FILE_NAME |grep "<"|grep -v "RECV MESG" |sed  's/^\[[^<]*</</'
#   echo
#done
```

I just wrote these code to grab some xml, but there are always ^M in the redirect result file(all lines but the echo line). After a lot of time experimenting, 'echo' seems the problem, without echo, everything is good. Same result under Mac OS X 10.9 and Ubuntu 12.04, here is the content in the result file: msg.sh > result

```
[      ] 15:22:42:150 esbclient_send.c:326 PID:4980956 TID:0 SID:759506         [DEBUG]SMSP: SEND MSEG: [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>^M
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">^M
  <soapenv:Body>^M
    <p0:sendSMS xmlns:p2="http://esb.xxxx.com" xmlns:p1="http://smsp.service.xxxx.com/abstraction/atomic/business.SmsSendService/schema/v1" xmlns:p0="http://smsp.service.xxxx.com/abstraction/atomic/business.SmsSendService/v1">^M
      <p2:requestHeader>^M
        <p2:version>1.0</p2:version>^M
        <p2:serialNo>783300013080100000000000003276500000</p2:serialNo>^M
        <p2:refSerialNo></p2:refSerialNo>^M
        <p2:requestId></p2:requestId>^M
        <p2:requestTime></p2:requestTime>^M
        <p2:timeOutTime></p2:timeOutTime>^M
        <p2:channelId></p2:channelId>^M
        <p2:channelSerialNo>783300013080100000000000003276500000</p2:channelSerialNo>^M
      </p2:requestHeader>^M
      <p1:msgID>0043559765</p1:msgID>^M
      <p1:phoneNum></p1:phoneNum>^M
      <p1:msgContent></p1:msgContent>^M
      <p1:bizKind></p1:bizKind>^M
      <p1:msgContent></p1:msgContent>^M
      <p1:bizKind></p1:bizKind>^M
      <p1:bizSys>330</p1:bizSys>^M
      <p1:bizCode>37371</p1:bizCode>^M
      <p1:dtSent></p1:dtSent>^M
      <p1:bizOrgan></p1:bizOrgan>^M
      <p1:bizTotal></p1:bizTotal>^M
      <p1:cardAccount></p1:cardAccount>^M
      <p1:bankBook>6216882031000005888</p1:bankBook>^M
      <p1:subAccount></p1:subAccount>^M
      <p1:dtBiz>20131011</p1:dtBiz>^M
      <p1:tmBiz>152052</p1:tmBiz>^M
      <p1:dtYear></p1:dtYear>^M
      <p1:dtMon></p1:dtMon>^M
      <p1:dtDay></p1:dtDay>^M
      <p1:dtHour></p1:dtHour>^M
      <p1:dtMin></p1:dtMin>^M
      <p1:bizTime>20130801152242</p1:bizTime>^M
      <p1:productName>SS1012</p1:productName>^M
      <p1:oldBalance></p1:oldBalance>^M
      <p1:moneyOut></p1:moneyOut>^M
      <p1:moneyIn></p1:moneyIn>^M
      <p1:balance></p1:balance>^M
      <p1:moneyIn></p1:moneyIn>^M
      <p1:balance></p1:balance>^M
      <p1:transAmount></p1:transAmount>^M
      <p1:borrowingFlag></p1:borrowingFlag>^M
      <p1:bizSeq></p1:bizSeq>^M
      <p1:period></p1:period>^M
      <p1:accrual></p1:accrual>^M
      <p1:accrualTax></p1:accrualTax>^M
      <p1:interestRate></p1:interestRate>^M
      <p1:subCode></p1:subCode>^M
      <p1:urgent></p1:urgent>^M
      <p1:ext1></p1:ext1>^M
    </p0:sendSMS>^M
  </soapenv:Body>^M
</soapenv:Envelope>^M
This is a test
```

Could anyone tell me why this happen and how can I avoid situation like this? thank you.

Comment: This is how it is *displayed* in a *particular environment* - the result of sed does *not* change. That is, *which* editor views the result file? As it's likely changing modes based on a heuristic..

Comment: I think editor display is a very likely answer, but to confirm, you can deconstruct each  process, and put `| cat -vet` after any part of the pipe-line to confirm if ^M chars are being added at that point. (cat -vet will display ^I for tab, ^M for \r and '$' at the end of each line. The '$' is NOT in the file. Good luck.

Comment: Is your question "how do I get rid of the ^M characters in the output from `sed`", or "how do I add a ^M character to the output from `echo`"? I suspect it happens because your original XML file has DOS-style line endings, but `echo` is only creating a *nix-style line ending...

Answer (score 0):

"^M" is how the CR (Carriage Return) character is displayed. ASCII code for this character is 13 or 0xOD. In C it is represented with '\r'. It is one of the end-of-line characters on non-Unix systems (I think Windows encodes end of lines as "\r\n" and MacOSX up to version 9 has "\r", while Unix and OS X have just "\n").

To get rid of these "^M" characters, simply delete them first with `tr` in your input file:

```
sed -n "1,52p" $FILE_NAME
```

should become

```
cat $FILE_NAME | tr -d '\r' | sed -n "1,52p"
```